# How do I allow immutable classes when the VisibilityModifier checkstyle module is enabled?

Tags: java, coding-style, immutability, verification, checkstyle

I work with a Java codebase that have strict [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html) checks, and it doesn't like the following immutable value object:

```
public class Foo {
    public final int bar;
    public final String baz;

    public Foo(int bar, String baz) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = baz;
    }
}
```

This is because the [VisibilityModifier](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#VisibilityModifier) module forces instance variables to be `private` and have getters.

1. Is there a way to make Checkstyle make an exception for instance variables that are `public final`?
2. If so, is there a way to make this exception only apply to test classes?

Comment: It makes sense that `final` members can be public. If I were you, I'd try to contact the Checkstyle developers and ask them about it, maybe they'll change it in the next version, or at least add a property.

Comment: Not exactly what you ask for, but you can add `// CHECKSTYLE_OFF: Visibility` above each class like that to get Checkstyle to stop complaining. I don't know of a setting which conditionally applies the rule.

Comment: I would generally argue that you don't want this. Even when the fields are final, you still expose the inner structure of your object, which will forever limit your future refactoring options. But that's a different discussion. :-)

Comment: @Thomas: That is a common misconception, yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to tell you this, and I know it may not be the answer you were hoping for, but:

It really is not possible out of the box, because the behavior is hardcoded in the check. Excerpt from the Checkstyle [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.puppycrawl.tools/checkstyle/5.6/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/design/VisibilityModifierCheck.java#VisibilityModifierCheck):

```java
if (!("private".equals(variableScope)
    || inInterfaceOrAnnotationBlock // implicitly static and final
    || (mods.contains("static") && mods.contains("final"))
    || ("package".equals(variableScope) && isPackageAllowed())
    || ("protected".equals(variableScope) && isProtectedAllowed())
    || ("public".equals(variableScope)
        && getPublicMemberRegexp().matcher(varName).find())))
{
    log(varNameAST.getLineNo(), varNameAST.getColumnNo(),
        "variable.notPrivate", varName);
}
```

You would have to [write your own check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), possibly as a subclass of `VisibilityModifierCheck` which overrides the method `visitToken()` in order to allow your exception.

On another note, if your class `Foo` is an inner class, then you can also simply declare the fields private and still access them from the outer class. Sort of a special case, but often one where the getters and setters are particularly annoying.